# Java DAO object make multthread?

Tags: multithreading, dao

I am using struts1.3 action layer with hibernate. I am accessing through HeperFactory patten to create helper instance to access DAO layer.
The helper factory seems to be Singleton but thread safe. When i do multiple updates its taking long time.
      Whan i want to achieve is there any design pattern or mechanism to achieve multi-threading helper access. Each and every thread(request) should have single helper instance per request for access dao.

```
I have two approaches
1. Using the singleton pattern (creating a single instance of each class and sharing them among threads)...
2. creating instances of the classes in each thread as and when they are needed.
```

How to achieve 2nd point? Is there any API or i should use pooling mechanism? Is there any issue in 2nd point(data loss)?

### This is my existing code :

### TaskAction.java

public class TaskAction{

```
public void udpateRecord(){
    ......
    TaskHelper taskHelper = (TaskHelper) HelperFactory
            .getHelperInstance(TaskHelper.class);
    taskHelper.updateRecord(daoObj);
    ......
}
```

}

### HelperFactory.java

```
public final class HelperFactory{
 public static Object getHelperInstance(Class<?> helperClass) {
        try {
            return LookUpFactory.getLookUpFactory().lookUpClass(helperClass);
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
     }
}
```

### LookUpFactory.java

```
public Object lookUpClass(String lookupClass)
        throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
    if (lookupClass == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "supplied lookupClass to lookup was null");
    }
    Object obj = this.objects.get(lookupClass);
    if (obj == null) {
        obj = Class.forName(lookupClass).newInstance();
        this.objects.put(lookupClass, obj);
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that database is not your bottleneck? Which isolation level is being used in db, not serializable? Are you sure that threads won't be updating same content and there will be no race conditions?

Comment: yes. There is no bottleneck in my database. But when i go with object creation with singleton class i could not achieve multi threading concept. My goal is access the dao layer with independant call